# validate Oracle non-SELECT query

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle-call-interface

Is there any way to check if an SQL query for Oracle would run successfully (by successfully I mean that the query is syntactically correct, all the table/column names exist, the user has proper permissions, etc.) without actually running it? The query may be not SELECT, but I do not want the changes to actually happen if it would modify any data.

I thought about something like:

```
$valid = false;
$stmt = oci_parse($db, $query);
if(!empty($stmt)) {
  $res = oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DESCRIBE_ONLY|OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
  if(!empty($res)) {
     $name = oci_field_name($res, 1);
     if(!empty($name)) {
       $valid = true;
     }
  }
  oci_rollback($db);
}
```

But if $query has some DDL in it, I understand that Oracle would commit it immediately. So is there any way to check the query without any modifications happening?

Comment: What happens during oci_parse?

Comment: @Shannon - from the oci_parse man page: "This function does not validate sql_text. The only way to find out if sql_text is a valid SQL or PL/SQL statement is to execute it." See http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php

Comment: I was going to suggest researching the parse procedure of the dbms_sql package, until I read the docs, "All statements are
parsed immediately. In addition, DDL statements are run immediately when parsed." So never mind.

Comment: Consider using flashback or point-in-time recovery, or simply writing a script to duplicate the schema for testing. Just because DDL is syntactically correct does not mean it is logically correct.

Comment: @vls that's what we're trying to do - try to run this query on a "fake" table, but it is unsafe and error-prone...

Answer (score 1):

You could create the query in a Package. If the package is created without error then the query must be correct.

Role based rights that can cause issues with any syntax check. Role based rights are not checked until runtil, so it is possible for a query to be correct at design time (because the developer has been granted direct rights to the tables) but fail at runtime (because the user has been granted the same rights in a role).

Comment: I need it only at runtime - e.g., app generates a set of queries and wants to ensure they are all fine before running them.

Comment: You can't put DDL directly in a PL/SQL package.  You can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to execute DDL from PL/SQL, but that doesn't give you any of the compile-time checking the OP is looking for.

Comment: I was thinking you would create the package at runtime, not at design time. No DDL in a package is correct. You could create a shadow schema that contains empty tables that look just like your real schema. Then you could execute commands against this empty data schema. You could even run DDL commands.

Answer (score 1):

**STEP 1:**

on your PHP code, create a string containing the text:

```
Dim myValidationString as string 

myValidationString = " create or replace procedure PROC_TEST_QUERY is " &
                     "       begin                                    " &
                     "         for i in (                             " &
                     "                   {MY_QUERY}                   " &
                     "                  ) loop                        " &
                     "             null;                              " &
                     "         end loop;                              " &
                     "       end;                                     "
```

**STEP 2:**

create a variable containing the SQLquery you want to validate:

```
Dim mySQLstring as string 

mySQLstring =  " SELECT *                               " &
               "   from all_objects                     " &
               "  where owner <> 'SYS'                  " &
               "    and created > sysdate -30           " &
               " UNION ALL                              " &
               " Select *                               " &
               "   from all_objects                     " &
               "  where owner = 'SYS'                   " &
               "    and object_name like 'T%'           " &
               "    and object_type in ('TABLE','VIEW') "
```

**STEP 3:**

replace the string content "{MY_QUERY}" with the content of the SQL statement you want to validate:

```
Dim myValidationStringToExecute as string

myValidationStringToExecute = replace(myValidationString, "{MY_QUERY}" , mySQLstring)
```

**STEP 4:**

execute the validation query:

```
DB.EXECUTE(myValidationStringToExecute)
```

**STEP 5:**

verify if the last call (DB.EXECUTE.....) raise an error.
 if yes, the query is invalid
 if no , the query is valid